# Bluemix: cf push using DEA instead of DIEGO architecture

Tags: ibm-cloud

When deploying an application into dedicated Bluemix it uses DEA architecture by default. How can I force it to use DIEGO architecture instead?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use more steps.  Deploy without start, switch to diego, start.

```
cf push APPLICATION_NAME --no-start
cf disable-diego APPLICATION_NAME
cf start APPLICATION_NAME
```

Ref [Deploying Apps](https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/manageapps/depapps.html#deployingapps)

Answer (score 0):

I built a bash exec to do this, which will use your existing manifest.yml file and pack all of this into a single request. The contents of the bash exec follow:

```
#!/bin/bash

filename="manifest.yml"
if [ -e $filename ];
then
  echo "using manifest.yml file in this directory"
else
  echo "no manifest.yml file found. exiting"
  exit -2
fi
shopt -s nocasematch
string='name:'
targetName=""
echo "Retrieving name from manifest file"
while read -r line
do
    name="$line"
    variable=${name%%:*}
    if [[ $variable == *"name"* ]]
    then
      inBound=${name#*:}
      targetName="$(echo -e "${inBound}" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//' -e 's/[[:space:]]*$//')"
    fi
done < "$filename"
if [ "$targetName" == "" ];
then
  echo "Could not find name of application in manifest.yml file. Cancelling build."
  echo "application name is identified by the 'name: ' term in the manifest.yml file"
  exit -1
else
  echo "starting cf push for $targetName"

  cf push --no-start

  echo "cf enable-diego $targetName"
  cf enable-diego $targetName

  echo "cf start $targetName"
  cf start $targetName

  exit 0
fi
```

Just put this code into your editor as a new file and then make the file executable. I keep a copy of this exec in each of my repos in the root directory. After doing a copy-paste and executing this exec, you may get the following error:

```
/bin/bash^M: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

If you do, just run the dos2unix command and it will 'fix up' the line endings to match your os.